# why to use following command in sqoop?

Tags: sqoop

I have a doubt in the following sqoop import command

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb \
--username user_name \
--table user_table \
--m 1 \
--target-dir /sample
```

why we use  **M** in the above command? please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-m is representing the mappers, by specifying -m 1 means you need only one mapper to be run to import the table. This is used for controlling parallelism. To achieve the parallelism sqoop uses the primary key/unique key to split the rows from source table.

Basically the default number of mappers in sqoop is 4. so for this you need to mention by which column you need to acheive parallelism using `--split-by column_name`, so by giving -m 1 you dont need splitting.

for more information check the below link,

[click here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism)

Comment: Thanks Sathiyan :)

Comment: Welcome Parbhu :)